# Facebook share preview not working when behind reverse proxy

Tags: facebook, iis, reverse-proxy

I host a website on Azure (Web App), but in front of it there is a reverse proxy server (Win Server 2012R2, IIS 8, ARR 3) to route `/blog` requests to another server.

If I try to share an url (`example.com`), there is no preview. But if I share original url (`site.azurewebsites.net`), preview works fine! 
Reverse proxy configuration is default one, latest ARR addon with one rule, routes to server farm with one server.  I do not block anything, just rewrite all request to `site.azurewebsites.net`. IIS logs looks ok, Facebook bot receives response status 200.

Also, in facebook debug tool (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) all tags and HTML are read correctly, but there is no preview on the bottom.